# How can I use the implementation of a base class for a pure virtual method of a interface class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have a BASE class implementing a virtual method f(). I also have a INTERFACE class, that has a pure virtual method f(). I then have a DERIVED class that inherits both the BASE and the INTERFACE. When I try to instantiate DERIVED I get an compiler error "cannot instantiate abstract class".

```
class BASE
{
    public:
    BASE() = default;
    ~BASE() = default;
    virtual void f(){}
};

class INTERFACE
{
    public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class DERIVED :
        public INTERFACE, public BASE
{
    public:
    DERIVED() = default;
    ~DERIVED() = default;
};
```

BASE class does not know INTERFACE, it is part of a library and I can not change it.
I read a few similar questions, but I could not find a clear answer as to how to solve this. What I need is to be able to instantiate DERIVED and be able to use f() from BASE in DERIVED as well as  when I access it through INTERFACE.

Comment: You need to write function `f()` in `DERIVED`, which may call `BASE::f()` in its implementation.

Comment: DERIVED should add `void f(){BASE::f();};`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Wh8obj84n Actually compiler's error is strightforward.. `because the following virtual functions are pure within 'DERIVED': 'virtual void INTERFACE::f()'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `void f()` of `INTERFACE` is never defined, `BASE` does not inherit from `INTERFACE`, so that is not an override of that function.

`DERIVED` does not define a `void f()`, so it also does not override that `INTERFACE` function, so that function has no body.

If you would want it to use the `BASE::f` to override `INTERFACE::f()`, either inherit `BASE` from `INTERFACE` or add an override in your `DERIVED` as such:

```
void f() override {BASE::f();}
```

Comment: could I just override the function with its own like this: ```void f() override {this->f();}```?

Comment: Well no, that would just cause an infinite loop of a function calling itself.